# Fetching multiple entities from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to fetch multiple entities from [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html). I have tried it in viewDidAppear function. However, since the data is a huge bulk, saved from remote JSON in server, fetching it seems to be taking time. I even followed this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial).
But fetching a huge data seems to be a little slow. Is there any better approach.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext!

    let TPTodayFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Constants.CoreDataEntities.TPTodayCoreDataEntity)

    let mahinaSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "month_np_id", ascending: true)
    TPTodayFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [mahinaSort]
    let error: NSError? = nil

    do {

        let patroDailyResults = try context!.executeFetchRequest(TPTodayFetchRequest) as? [TPToday]


        if let results = patroDailyResults
        {
            patroDaily = results
        }
        else
        {
            print("Couldn't fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }


    self.refreshUI()
}
```

Now my question is, what is the best approach to fetch entities from CoreData so that the fetching process goes smooth and that doesn't affect the application performance. This code snippet perfectly works for fetching, but I want to make it quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can make it faster, however such long running operations shouldn't be run on main thread.

Instead you should follow this pattern to do fetching on background thread and once it's finished update affected UI:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // fetch data
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update some UI
    }
}
```

Comment: I recently got the idea of running the fetching in background method and refreshing the UI back in the main thread. I also did a mistake in trying to run the fetching in the `viewWillAppear()` method, which should have run on `viewDidLoad()_` method as for my case. Anyways, thank you for your answer! @Wujo